# How to get values from Json String with the provided format

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I am converting the datatable into Json string using

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
```

and i am receiving the following string.

```
{{
  "CheckUserResult": "{\"Table\":[{\"User_ID\":4,\"User_Name\":\"IKERocks\",\"User_Email\":\"bamane1989@gmail.com\",\"User_PhoneNumber\":\"8452046777\",\"User_DateOfBirth\":\"\\/Date(1485845400000+0530)\\/\",\"User_City\":\"Pune\",\"User_Admin\":null,\"User_Points\":10,\"User_Login_Provider\":\"Google\"}]}"
}}
```

now I need to retrieve the values into my object.

```
Userdetails.User_Email = Convert.ToString(userdata["User_Email"])
```

I am getting null always.

whats the correct syntax to get the key value pair?

Comment: I checked that you json is not valid. Please check properly and firt you need to parse it to get the key values.

Comment: What do you expect? How should User_Email look like?

Comment: What code is wrapping the serialized data table in a "CheckUserResult"?  And what code is serializing *that* to JSON?  The problem is your data table is getting double-serialized as a result of this process.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build a class

```
public class UserDetails
{  
    public int User_ID{  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string User_Name{  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string User_Email{  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
   ....
}  

string jsonData = "{\'User_ID\':4,\'User_Name\':\'IKERocks\',\'User_Email\':\'bamane1989@gmail.com\'}";
var myDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails>(jsonData);
```

and after you can do this

```
String Username = myDetails.User_Name;

Userdetails.User_Email = myDetails.User_Email
```

Comment: tried and getting error at var myDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <UserDetails> (jsonData);

Comment: I already had a UserDetails class. and when I add this line of code.. it gives below error.

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<F_V.Models.UsersModel>(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @PraveenBamane I edited my answer, you have to use a jsonData like that

Comment: Thanks martina.. but I had already tried that part to get a Json as you posted and it's working. But my question was why doesn't JsonConvert.SerializeObject and JsonConvert.DeSerializeObject works

Answer (score 0):

this code maybe help you :

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table) 
{  
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
    List < Dictionary < string, object >> parentRow = new List < Dictionary < string, object >> ();  
    Dictionary < string, object > childRow;  
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) 
    {  
        childRow = new Dictionary < string, object > ();  
        foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) 
        {  
            childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);  
        }  
        parentRow.Add(childRow);  
    }  
    return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);  
}
```

Comment: tried this also.. but I am getting below Json string.. and still unable to get data from it.

{"CheckUserResult":"[{\"User_ID\":4,\"User_Name\":\"IKERocks\",\"User_Email\":\"bamane1989@gmail.com\",\"User_PhoneNumber\":\"8452046777\",\"User_DateOfBirth\":\"\\\/Date(1485845400000)\\\/\",\"User_City\":\"Pune\",\"User_Admin\":null,\"User_Points\":10,\"User_Login_Provider\":\"Google\"}]"}


how do I get data from this string to a local variable

Comment: {"CheckUserResult":"   -- why this part gets added in my json string?